# Why this is a valid syntax in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
const arr = [(firstName = 'hello')]
```

Why the above code is valid code in javascript. I didn't understand why this is not throwing any error.

Comment: You are not showing anything "above". Please edit your question and make sure you include the code.

Comment: No code is technically valid javascript, but I doubt you meant that.

Comment: Why would it not be? What specifically about it seems off? (The `()` is unnecessary, and the assignment may be creating an implicit global, but...)

Comment: Looks valid. An assignment on string will return `true`. So its basically `const arr = [ true ]`

Comment: This should be valid in most programming languages, I presume. Most of the times, parentheses are used to divide more complex structures of code for better visualisation or so that you enforce some operators to come first (complex conditions involving `&&` and `||` could be a use case). In your case, this is not necessary, but it is till not enforced NOT to be used.

Comment: @mardubbles - No, it'll result in `const arr = ["hello"]`. The result of assignment is the value that was being assigned.

Comment: When we console log are it is showing like ['hello'], which is an array

Comment: That indeed @T.J.Crowder. The parenthesis made me think it would be treated altogether as an expression on *truthy*. And since its an assignment, not an equality, would add true to the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what that code does and any it's valid.

That code does this:

```
firstName = 'hello';
const arr = ['hello'];
```

...except `'hello'` is only evaluated once in your code. (In the case of a literal like `'hello'` it doesn't matter that it's only evaluated once, but if it were a function call or similar, it would matter: in your code, it would be called once, but in the above it would be called twice.)

It's valid because:

- Using the result of an assignment operation is valid; the result of an assignment operation is the value being assigned. So the expression `firstName = 'hello'` results in the value `'hello'`.
- The grouping operator (`()`) can be used where any expression can be used; the result of the grouping operation is the result of the expression within it.
- `[x]` creates an array with `x` in it.
- `const arr = /*...*/` creates a constant (a read-only variable) and assigns it the result of evaluating the *initializer expression* (the expression on the right-hand side of the `=`).

So all of the parts are valid and they're assembled in a valid way. The identifier `arr` is declared; the `firstName = 'hello'` assignment expression is evaluated, setting `firstName` and resulting in `'hello'`; the grouping operation `('hello')` is evaluated resulting in `'hello'`; the array literal `['hello']` is evaluated creating an array; and the `arr` constant is initialized with the array reference.

One wrinkle is that it *looks like* `firstName` is an undeclared identifier (your code doesn't declare it anywhere, there's no `let firstName` or similar). If it's really undeclared, then this is one of the unfortunate quirks of JavaScript in loose mode: assigning to an undeclared identifier implicitly creates a global variable (I call it [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html)). This is one of many reasons to use [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) (`"use strict"` at the top of the file, or use JavaScript native modules ["ESM"]; the body of a `class` definition is also always strict). In strict mode, assigning to an undeclared identifier is the error it always should have been.